# Как сделать кнопку с имитацией загрузки?

Tags: javascript, анимация, загрузка

Приветствую!
Помогите новичку.
Как сделать кнопку с имитацией загрузки (в течение 3-5 секунд), по типу как здесь [Анимация при нажатии кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434010/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Но чтобы после окончания имитации загрузки, рядом (или ниже) с кнопкой выдавалось определенное сообщение текстом?

Comment: а что именно загружается?

Comment: Ничего. Я же написал "имитация загрузки". Так скажем просто 3-5 секундная пауза, во время которой крутится колесико загрузки или полоса загрузки без разницы... а потом анимация загрузки исчезает и рядом появляется надпись (только не спрашивайте какая :)  )

Comment: так в приведенном примере уже все есть - просто добавьте текст и все

Comment: Что правда? Ну надо же)))

Comment: Уважаемый, если бы я знал, как и что и куда добавить, я бы не лез на кодерский ресурс за помощью. Если для вас это так просто, то не выложите мне готовый вариант?

Comment: Мда... Я думал на этом портале есть знающие люди, для которых такая проблема - мелочь...

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь я правильно понял Вопрос. Троблер взял css-ный не ругайтесь.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //подвешиваем на событие клик по кнопке
  $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    //отключение ее
    $(e.currentTarget).attr('disabled', true);
    // показываем процесс закгрузки
    $('.loader').toggleClass('hide');

    // подвешиваем паузу на 5 секунд
    setTimeout(function() {
      // скрываем процесс загрузки
      $('.loader').toggleClass('hide');
      // делаем кнопку активной
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('disabled', false);
      // добавляем текст о том что загрузка успешно закончилась
      $(e.currentTarget).after('<div>Загрузка завершена</div>');
    }, 5000)
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.loader {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 72px auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation: load6 1.7s infinite ease;
  animation: load6 1.7s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load6 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  5%,
  95% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  10%,
  59% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, -0.087em -0.825em 0 -0.42em #999999, -0.173em -0.812em 0 -0.44em #999999, -0.256em -0.789em 0 -0.46em #999999, -0.297em -0.775em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, -0.338em -0.758em 0 -0.42em #999999, -0.555em -0.617em 0 -0.44em #999999, -0.671em -0.488em 0 -0.46em #999999, -0.749em -0.34em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  38% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, -0.377em -0.74em 0 -0.42em #999999, -0.645em -0.522em 0 -0.44em #999999, -0.775em -0.297em 0 -0.46em #999999, -0.82em -0.09em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
}
@keyframes load6 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  5%,
  95% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  10%,
  59% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, -0.087em -0.825em 0 -0.42em #999999, -0.173em -0.812em 0 -0.44em #999999, -0.256em -0.789em 0 -0.46em #999999, -0.297em -0.775em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, -0.338em -0.758em 0 -0.42em #999999, -0.555em -0.617em 0 -0.44em #999999, -0.671em -0.488em 0 -0.46em #999999, -0.749em -0.34em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  38% {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, -0.377em -0.74em 0 -0.42em #999999, -0.645em -0.522em 0 -0.44em #999999, -0.775em -0.297em 0 -0.46em #999999, -0.82em -0.09em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    box-shadow: 0 -0.83em 0 -0.4em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.42em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.44em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.46em #999999, 0 -0.83em 0 -0.477em #999999;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button">Загрузить</button>
  <div class="loader hide"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bear GRiZZLY Xi, Да!!! Спасибо огромное!! Это именно то, что надо. Кнопку то я сам заменю - не проблема)) Единственное, подскажите нубу пожалуйста, куда вставлять первые два блока? Последний я понял, что в html-страницу.

Comment: Простите не до конца понял фразу "куда вставлять первые два блока"? Вы имели ввиду: <button id="button">Загрузить</button>
  <div class="loader hide"></div> Или что то другое?

Comment: Так по ходу дела вы (@Алексей) про JS и CSS?
Их можно положить рядом в файлах mani.js для JS и style.css для CSS
затем в секции  <head> добавить <script src="main.js"></script> для JS и <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

Comment: @Алексей Если я Вам помог нажмите стрелочку вверх около моего ответа или пометку что этот ответ помог :-) 
Мне будет приятно.

Comment: А если уже есть файл style.css, то можно ли добавить Ваши строки в него? Или лучше создать и подключить новый css-файл? Извиняюсь за нубство.

Comment: Да можете @Алексей. Просто скопируйте все строки из моего CSS и вставьте в конце своего файла или в начале, как Вам удобно.

Comment: еще раз огромное спасибо за помощь! Стрелочку вверх нажал, но проявтися, когда я наберу 15 баллов - так написали. Пометку, что ответ мне помог не вижу, к сожалению.

Comment: Хз всё сделал, но вместо того, чтобы работало, как здесь, после нажатия кнопки окно просто перезагружается и кидает вверх страницы. (((

Comment: Не понятно, почему скрипт вообще перезагружает всю страницу. Наверное у меня что то не так на самой странице что конфликтует со скриптом.

Comment: Сделал вообще пустую страницу, где только Ваш нижний код + подключение стиля и js - кнопка работает в холостую... Что то уже и не знаю. Всё перепробовал.

Comment: @Алексей Сделал для вас сборку сложил в [zip](http://joxi.ru/Ra2XgVFy0ndjmg) **все**, зарархивируйте и запускайте там все работает проверил.

Comment: Ух! Вот это спасибо Вам!))) Теперь всё работает, как часы)

Comment: А можно узнать, как вместо обычной кнопки привязать всё это к моей кнопке?

Comment: У меня вот такая: <button class='btn btn-primary' id='check-pay' type='button' 'javascript:void(0);' class='btn paycheck' onclick="paycheck($('#order_input').val(),$('#comment_input').val());">Загрузить</button>

Comment: @Алексей Я бы немного изменил ваш код или уже мой. Если Ваш, то надо из **<button class='btn btn-primary' id='check-pay' type='button' 'javascript:void(0);' class='btn paycheck' onclick="paycheck($('#order_input').val(),$('#comment_input').val());">Загрузить‌​</button>** сделать -  **<button class='btn btn-primary' id='check-pay' class='btn paycheck' onclick="paycheck($('#order_input').val(),$('#comment_input').val());">Загрузить‌​</button>** а в моем **js code** изменить **#button** на ваш **#check-pay**

Comment: так не работает (( просто кидает вверх страницы

Comment: @Алексей Может вы просто дадите ссылку на вашу страницу, в реальном интернете, на месте легче понять, что у Вас там творится...

Comment: Проблема в моем firefox. В хроме всё нормально работает. Незнаю, что с файром...

Comment: К сожалению с Вашим браузером придется Вам разбираться.

Comment: Нет дело не в браузере все таки. Вот то, что вы прислали в архиве - работает как часы! Но если пытаюсь заменить кнопку на Ваши изменения, то страница просто обновляется и кидает вверх страницы.

Comment: Кстати, попробовал вставить вот это: <button class='btn btn-primary' id='check-pay' class='btn paycheck' onclick="paycheck($('#order_input').val(),$('#comment_input').val());">Загрузить‌​‌​</button> в ВАШУ присланную пустую страницу (все три файла в отдельной папке) + изменить файл-js = получилось вообще что после нажатия, 5-ти секундная пауза и потом выдается сообщение. Даже колесика нет :) И сама кнопка обычная - не синяя.

Comment: Попробуйте сами

Comment: <button class='btn btn-primary' id='check-pay' class='btn paycheck' onclick="paycheck($('#order_input').val(),$('#comment_input').val());">Загрузить‌​‌​</button> - что-то не так в этом выражении.

Comment: В общем разобрался думаю в чем проблема. То, что Вы прислали в архиве, хорошо работает на локалке. Но когда закидываешь это на сервер - оно вообще не работает. Кнопка жмется вхолостую.

Comment: Ох... если Вы все таки дадите адрес вашего сайта я смогу Вам помочь. Ибо все что вы пробовали не будет работать. Мои файлы три в будут работать. Но это будет уже утром

Comment: Так наступило утро...
Выкладываю два варианта. [1. Вариант](http://sevastopol.town/source/load/) - Мои три файла
[2. Вариант](http://sevastopol.town/source/load2/) - Мои три файла с внесеной кнопкой из вашего комментария.
Как видите все работает.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но у вас даже сайт ваш не работает. Вот смотрите: http://c2n.me/3rwfxRu

Comment: Я не знаю что за сриншот вы выложили. Он не связан с моили ссылками никак. Все работает и по 1 ссылке и по второй.

Comment: Вот теперь работает) Уважаемый, а можно мне второй вариант архивом? Прям так, как есть у вас на сервере. Попробую на своем поставить.

Comment: @Алексей
По первой ссылке на моейм сервере то что было в первом архиве.
По второй ссылке файлы одним архивом: [zip 2](http://joxi.ru/DBA0JdSBBqBEmy)

Comment: Действительно. Если загружать то, что дали Вы чисто без остального (моего), то всё работает. Если внедрить это в мой сайт, то не работает. Видимо что-то с чем-то конфликтует. Буду искать причину у себя. Большое спасибо за помощь.